# expect command is not working in bash script

Tags: expect, spawn

I have a problem related to expect.

when i run abc.sh which includes following lines

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 192.168.0.12:/tmp
######################
expect {
-re "password:" {
exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
}
}
interact
```

its works fine

but when i use similar code in my running script it doesnt work

---

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
while read -u3 LINE
do
code .........
code .......
code  ........

REMOTE_COMMANDS1="scp -r -v $BASE_DIRECTORY/$USERNAME $D_IPADDRESS:/home/"

spawn $REMOTE_COMMANDS1
######################
expect {
-re "password:" {
exp_send "redhat\r"
}
}
interact


done 3< /opt/sitelist.txt
```

**it gives error**

./script.sh: line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./script.sh: line 62:`}'

i think it is due to the fact that i am not including #!/usr/bin/expect in top of the script but if i use this and execute my script it doesnt do any thing and display all of code in terminal after excution. so can we include #!/usr/bin/expect and #!/bin/bash simultaneously ?

Regards, 
Aditya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course bash cannot interpret expect commands, just as bash cannot interpret Java/Perl/Python syntax. There are a couple of approaches.

Write the expect script as a separate program and invoke it from the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
while read -u3 LINE
do
    #...
    ./expect_scp.exp "$BASE_DIR" "$D_IPADDRESS" "$USERNAME" "$PASSWORD"
done 3< /opt/sitelist.txt
```

and `expect_scp.exp` is

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set base_dir  [lindex $argv 0]
set remote_ip [lindex $argv 1]
set username  [lindex $argv 2]
set password  [lindex $argv 3]
# or
foreach {base_dir remote_ip username password} $argv {break}

spawn scp -rv $base_dir/$username $remote_ip:/home/
expect -re "password:"
exp_send -- "$password\r"
interact
```

You *can* put the expect script inside the bash script with proper attention to quoting. Fortunately single quotes are not special to expect.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
export BASE_DIR D_IPADDRESS USERNAME PASSWORD
while read -u3 LINE
do
    #...
    expect -c '
        spawn scp -rv $env(BASE_DIR)/$env(USERNAME) $env(D_IPADDRESS):/home/
        expect -re "password:"
        exp_send -- "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
        interact
    '
done 3< /opt/sitelist.txt
```

Comment: this is really helpful to me !! tks ~~ BTW , why i used the first method(call expect script from a sh script) it keep warning , "skipped . " , how can i solve this ?

Comment: @JasonHuang, ask a question in an actual question, and provide more details.

Comment: @glennjackman : When i call expect script in my bash script. I am getting the following error message. /usr/bin/expect bad interpreter. No such file found. My code : !#/bin/bash -x    ./installer_binary.exp > /tmp/Scanner.log 2>&1

Comment: "bad interpreter" usually means you have dos-style line endings. use `dos2unix` on the script file.